# MySQL return list of each parent and its children

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, mysql-workbench, recursive-query

I have a table like below:

Manager is the parent and has child resources under him that are joined to manager's parent id.

```
id    | parent_id   |   Role       | Number of roles

123   | 123         | Manager      |    2

124   | 123         | Resource     |    1

125   | 123         | Resource     |    2

128   | 128         | Manager      |    1

126   | 128         | Resource     |    4

127   | 128         | Resource     |    3
```

My sql query should return the below result for each parent:

```
id    | parent_id   |   Role       | Sum of manager only | Total resources

123   | 123         | Manager      |    2                |    2+1+2 = 5 (Manager + the total number of resources for parent id 123)   

128   | 128         | Manager      |    1                |    1+4+3 = 8 (Manager + the total number of resources for parent id 128)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sub query should be last option, because it will slow down your system.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do:

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, m2.sum_roles
FROM
    managers_workers m1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        parent_id, SUM(num_of_roles) AS sum_roles
    FROM
        managers_workers
    GROUP BY parent_id) AS m2 ON m1.id = m2.parent_id
WHERE
    m2.parent_id IS NOT NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do self join using parent id. if you table name is "tbl_manager"

```
SELECT t1.id,
    SUM(IF(t1.id = t2.id, 1,0)) AS is_manager,
    t1.parent_id, 
    t1.Role, 
    t1.Number_of_Role AS Sum_of_manager_only,
    IFNULL(SUM(t2.Number_of_Role),0) AS Total_resources 
FROM  tbl_manager AS t1 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_manager AS t2 
    ON t2.parent_id = t1.id 
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING is_manager;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery

```
select
    (select id from mytbl where id=r.parent_id)  id
    ,r.parent_id
    ,(select sum(NofRole) from mytbl where parent_id=r.parent_id and Role='Manager') [Sum of manager only]
    , sum(r.nofrole) [Total resources]
    from mytbl r
    group by r.parent_id
```